# How to open a GUI-Application on a Server (Raspi) via SSH using python/paramiko?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, x11, paramiko, x11-forwarding

As server I got a Raspberry Pi with a display connected by hdmi. From my Windows 10 pc I whant to execute a gui-application on my Pi by ssh, so that the application get's displayed on the Pi's display. The execution should be started by a Python program using paramiko.

If I try the following in the windows-console it works perfectly fine:

- ssh -X user@raspberrypi
- export DISPLAY=:0
- python3 my_gui_app.py

But if I try the following in a python script, it runs without error, but **no window pops up** at the Pi's screen:

```
import paramiko

hostname = "raspberrypi"
username = "user"
password = "1234"
command = "python3 my_gui_app.py"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)

    with client.get_transport().open_session() as session:
        session.get_pty()
        session.request_x11(single_connection=True)
        session.set_environment_variable("DISPLAY", ":0")
        session.exec_command(command)

        # Continuously read the stdout and stderr streams
        while True:
            if session.recv_ready():
                stdout = str(session.recv(4096).decode("utf-8"))
                print(stdout, end="")
            if session.recv_stderr_ready():
                stderr = str(session.recv_stderr(4096).decode("utf-8"))
                print(stderr, end="")

            # Check if the command has finished executing
            if session.exit_status_ready():
                break

finally:
    client.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

On the server, In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , there will be an option called `AcceptEnv` that allows the ssh client to send environment variables.
When setting the environment variable using `session.set_environment_variable()`, the environment variable should also present in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Use the below command to verify:

`grep AcceptEnv /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

If `DISPLAY` variable is not present, add the it and restart SSHD service.

If you can not update/edit the sshd_config of server, update your command

> command = "export DISPLAY=:0; python3 my_gui_app.py"

Comment: What do you mean by *"the environment variable should also present in /etc/ssh/sshd_config"*?